# Regex: How to return matches that are not in the bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

So I technically already solved this issue, but I was hoping for a better solution using some funky regex.

The issue is:
We got strings this:

2+{2+(2)},

10+(20+2)+2

The goal is to match the 'plus' signs that are not in any sort of bracket.
i.e. in the previous strings it should match

2 **+** {2+(2)} ,

10 **+** (20+2) **+** 2

at the moment what I am doing is matching **all** plus signs, and then checking to see if the sign has any bracket in front of it (using regex), if it does then get rid of it.

I was hoping for a neater regex solution, is that possible?

To reiterate, I need the location of the strings, at the moment I am using javascript to do this, so ideally a js solution is preferred, but the pattern is really what I am looking for.

Comment: post your code that works...

Comment: You might want to consider using a parser for this.

Comment: @JordanHendrix I'd rather not, its lengthy and very easily replicatable anyhow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you link me to what you mean?

Comment: There is no way to do that with regex in javascript. writing a parser is a good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood what you want to do. Could you post an input/output sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps just replace everything inside `()` or `{}` with spaces:

```
'10 + (20+2) + 2'.replace(/\([^)]*?\)|\{[^}]*?\}/g, m => ' '.repeat(m.length));
```

This would result in

```
10 +        + 2
```

Meaning the position of the strings aren't changed.

Note: It won't work well with nested things of the same type, ex `(1 + (1 + 1) + 1)`, but it works with `(1 + { 1 + 1 } + 1)`.

---

Bigger solution, using the same logic, but that works with nested stuff

```
var input = '10 + { 1 + (20 + (1 + { 3 + 3 } + 1) + 2) + 2 }';

var result = [];
var opens = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
  var ch = input[i];
  if (/\(|\{/.test(ch)) {
    opens++;
    result[i] = ' ';
  }
  else if (/\)|\}/.test(ch)) {
    opens--;
    result[i] = ' ';
  }
  else {
    if (!opens) result[i] = input[i];
    else result[i] = ' ';
  }
}

result = result.join('');
// "10 +                                           "
```

Comment: Oh, I actually like that solution a lot actually, not what I was looking for, but it does simplify my code a lot :)
I didn't know you can pass functions to replace like that!
thanks!

Comment: Now it is not so pretty but it hopefully can handle nested things. It can probably be optimized somehow...

Comment: the second part is not exactly, but the first part did simplify everything :)
I ended up creating this function call `findAll` that basically ran .search to find every index of the pattern. 
Then I ran 
var search = findAll(val.replace(/\([^)]*?\)|\{[^}]*?\}/g, m => ' '.repeat(m.length)),reg);

and used the indices, to find everything else I needed :)

Comment: it's better. Note that it's also possible to use your first approach in a while loop until there is nothing to replace but to do that you must forbid all brackets to only match the innermost: `\([^()]*\)|{[^{}]*}`. *(however the complexity of this way grows with the nesting level)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that is basically what I ended up doing :)
Thanks!